# moving jquery function to external js file

Tags: jquery, syntax, format, external

I have a jquery function that works great hard coded onto the html page right above the head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>    
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#side-menu').sidr();
});
</script>
</head>
```

however when i move this to the external .js file that is also right above the head tag, it doesn't work. I'm formatting it on the external.js file like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#side-menu').sidr();
});
```

and including my external.js file on the html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/external.js"></script>
</head>
```

is there some syntax i'm missing?

Comment: you need to include your external js file.

Comment: and include it after you include jQuery

Comment: yup, doing that. just edited my question to reflect that. any other reasons it might not be working? thanks guys!

Comment: Have you included the sidr plugin library?

Comment: yup, no typos, but it's definitely not loading. when hard coded it adds a class to the #side-menu div, but when extrnal and i check the source that class hasn't been added.

i see this answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600264/why-jquery-click-doesnt-work-when-included-in-a-separate-file

but i'm not sure what i'm supposed to wrap the function in. his example is a bit different than mine and i'm not advanced enough to know how to modify it. thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your page I don't know how you are laying it all out, but since it works inline but not externally you could make sure you put:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/external.js"></script>
```

...in the same place as you had:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#side-menu').sidr();
});
```

Comment: That was it! i had the order mixed up with other scripts, that's why it wasn't running. can't believe i didn't notice that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

The jquery src should be always above those external .js files that use jquery.