# How can I access the function which inside different js file in JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a script which named Normal.js in the HTML:

```
$(function () {    
    function WhiteNav() {
        $("#LOGO>img").attr('src', '/images/LOGOWhite.svg');
        $("#NavUL a").css("color", "#cecece");
    }    
});
```

And here is the struct of the HTML as below:
[image]

However, after the browser(Chrome) ran the WhiteNav function in the script, it reported this error and the WhiteNav failed:
[image]

Why it turned out to be this? It seems like I ran the code with a different file, is it right? I tried the way as [Why jQuery click doesn't work when included in a separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600264/why-jquery-click-doesnt-work-when-included-in-a-separate-file) said but failed again.
What's wrong with this? How can I solve this problem? Would you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: @TylerRoper Thank you very much, now it works! Would you mind I create a new answer with what you said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring `WhiteNav` inside of a `function() { ... }`, meaning it will only be accessible from within that function.

Simply remove the `$(function () { ... });` from around it, and it will be declared *globally* - accessible from anywhere after it's declaration.

As a side-note, you can remove `$(function () { ... });` from your internal `<script>` snippet as well. `$(function () { ... });` and `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` are identical and so there is no need for both. The latter is just shorthand.